# Two dice are rolled. A = First die is odd, B = sum of two dice is 9. Are A and B independent or disjoint? Find P(A and B), P(A or B)

Tags: probability, independence, dice

> Two dice are rolled. $A$ is the event that the first die is odd and $B$ is the event that the sum of two dice is $9$. Are $A$ and $B$ independent or disjoint? Find $P(A \cap B), P(A \cup B)$.

I have $$P(A) = \frac{1}{2}, P(B) = \frac{4}{36}.$$
I calculated
$P(A\cap B)$ as $P(A) \times P(B|A)$ to get
$$P(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{2} *\frac{2}{36} = \frac{1}{36}.$$Then, I computed $P(A \cup B)$ as $P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$ and got $$P(A \cup B)=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{4}{36} - \frac{1}{36} = \frac{21}{36}.$$
I believe the events are dependent but the question seems to want independent or disjoint.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint as they have outcomes in common (e.g. $(3,6)$). Two events are said to be independent if the occurrence of one event in any way does not imply anything about the occurrence of another. I don't know exactly, but I think they are dependent, because if $A$ occurs, then somehow $B$ is influenced.

Comment: Anyways, I think that your reasoning and answers are correct.

Comment: Where did 2/36 cone from in your calculation of P(A and B)? (As a side note, I think you should do without formulas for this problem, and just count cases. It's easier to avoid mistakes that way. Or even better, do both and compare.)

Answer (score 2):

Your answers are incorrect!

1. There are two favourable events: $(3;6)$ and $(5;4)$

$$P(A\cap B)=\frac{2}{36}$$

2. As a direct consequence you have

$$P(A \cup B)= \frac{20}{36}$$

The two event are (correctly) NOT disjointed as $P(A \cap B)>0$

3. The two events are independent: in fact, by definition, two events $A,B$ are independent if and only if

$$P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$$

or equivalently:

$P(B)=P(B|A)$

$P(A)=P(A|B)$

In your example, you have

$P(B)=\frac{4}{36}=\frac{1}{9}$

and $P(B|A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}=\frac{1}{9}$